# $L = L\bigl((b \cup ab \cup aab)^*(\lambda \cup a \cup aa)\bigr)$ . how does $bbbbbbabaabaa$ belong to L?

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $L$ be the language generated by the regular expression $(b \cup ab \cup aab)^*(\lambda \cup a \cup aa)$. how does bbbbbbabaabaa belong to L?

I know
$(b \cup ab \cup aab)^*$ can be translated to $bbbbbb$

and $(\lambda \cup a \cup aa)$ can be translated to $aa$

then where does abaab come from?
is it from $(b \cup ab \cup aab)^*$? 
if so, i thought $\cup$ was a "either or" statement, not a "both or all" statement.

so $(b \cup ab \cup aab)$ can be:

$b$ or $ab$ or $aab$. but not $babaab$ or definitely $bbbbbbabaab$.

I'm assuming i'm not fully understanding a minor concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Like this: $(b)(b)(b)(b)(b)(b)(ab)(aab)(aa)$. In $L = (b \cup ab \cup aab)^* (\lambda \cup a \cup aa)$ the connective $\cup$ (in other notations $|$ symbol) behaves much like a set union, i.e. $(a \cup b)^2$ would denote $\{aa,ab,ba,bb\}$ in analogy to $(\{a\} \cup \{b\})^2$.

Comment: @dtldarek, thanks alot! crystal clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is generated by the regular expression $(b\cup ab\cup aab)^*(\lambda\cup a\cup aa)$. If $bbbbbbabaabaa\in L$, clearly we must match the final $aa$ with the $aa$ alternative of $\lambda\cup a\cup aa$, so the initial segement $bbbbbbabaab$ must match $(b\cup ab\cup aab)^*$. And it does:

$$bbbbbbabaab=(b)(b)(b)(b)(b)(b)(ab)(aab)\;,\tag{1}$$

where each expression in parentheses matches one of the alternatives of $b\cup ab\cup aab$. Since the star of this permits us to concatenate any finite number of instance of any of these three alternatives, $(1)$ is generated by $(b\cup ab\cup aab)^*$, and $bbbbbbabaabaa$ is generated by the original regular expression.